# What is the string compression algorithm?

Tags: encryption, compression, reverse-engineering

I am reversing an old game for translate it, here is the compression algorithm , I want to know what algorithm this is.

the following is the python pseudocode

```py
while True:
    byte = rawdata[praw]
    low_byte  = byte & 0xF
    high_byte = byte >> 4 
    for i in range(low_byte):
        buffer[pbuffer] = rawdata[praw]
        pbuffer += 1
        praw += 1
    
    for i in range(high_byte):
        low_byte2  = rawdata[praw] & 0xF
        high_byte2 = rawdata[praw] >> 4

        p = pbuffer - low_byte - 1
        for i in range(high_byte2):
            buffer[pbuffer] = buffer[p]
            pbuffer += 1
            praw += 1
```

if `low_byte` or `high_byte` is `0`, will call this function

```
def func(data):
    # do...while...
    while data is even number:
        data = (data << 7) | rwadata[praw]
        p += 1
        if (data & 1) != 0:
            break
    return (data >> 1)
```

Comment: You want to know this algorithm is called? Well, it might have no name at all.

Comment: yes.I can decompress it, but I don't konw how compress it.

Comment: Your code looks wrong, and it is incomplete since you do not actually have if statements for "if low_byte or high_byte is 0, will call this function". Call it before? After? Instead of? In addition to? The code looks wrong since you are writing the same byte to the buffer you pulled the two nybbles from. That makes no sense. You should only post _complete_ and _correct_ code that has been _tested_.